# How can I let the server define the view and optionally the controller when the route changes in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-routing

I don't want to hardcode views and controllers in the normal way by using the $routeProvider configuration.

Basically I want to subsribe to the routechanged event, call some logic on the server providing the current route, and get the appropriate view / controller returned as json ( as a promise ),  and then have it compiled / displayed inside the main section of the app.

It seems like a trivial problem, but I haven't found a solution yet.

I've tried replacing the ng-view with ng-include, but i'm not able to dynamically change the ng-controller on it.

I've tried creating a custom directive which optionally wraps the ng-include in a div with ng-controller if it is provided, but since this executes inside template function, i'm not able to resolve the controller name, because the template function does not have access to scope

If any one can show me the path, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: none of this functionality is built into angular without using a third party lazy loader module

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up doing this in my controller, which seems to work:

```
function loadPage(page) {

    var container = $("#main");
    var element = $("<div>");
    var scope = $rootScope.$new();

    server.loadViewTemplate(page.view).then(function(template) {
        element.html(template);
        container.html(element);
        if (page.controller) {
            var templateController = $controller(page.controller, { $scope: scope });
            element.children().data('$ngControllerController', templateController);
        }
        $compile(element)(scope);
    });


}
```